# Trigger form with specific content for Paypal

Tags: jquery, ajax, paypal

I copy the code from Paypal as below, how can I trigger the click for the image and pass it for ajax submit? What is the code if I want to trigger the < input type="image" src="…" >?

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" value="eDM">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="T7QER8GC5FTBS">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal  The safer, easier way to pay online.">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `.submit()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)).

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event,
>   or trigger that event on an element.
>   The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form. It can only be attached to  elements. Forms can
>   be submitted either by clicking an explicit ,
>   , or , or by pressing Enter
>   when certain form elements have focus.

Comment: Thanks PayPal_Robert but I have no idea how to write the code such as $('from.has(input[.....]').click, something like that.